# How to use Yolo 5 converted models

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, yolo, yolov5

Yolo 5 is an object detection model that can be exported to several different frameworks including TensorFlow and Core ML.
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5

I have been able to train a Yolo 5 model, and export it to TensorFlow (TF1 graph def, or TF2 savemodel), and tried Apple Core ML.

I have not been able to find any examples for Yolo 5 on how to use these models once exported.
i.e. how to take an image file and get the detected objects/labels/coordinates

I tried similar python code to TF1 object detection, but the exported model does not seem compatible,
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/tensorflow-1.14/

neither with TF2,
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/object_detection

or TFlite,
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview

Comment: Hey James! Nice to see you back. Is this for android or iOs?

Comment: both Android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

Use the weights that YOLOv5 calculated after training. They are usually in this route:

> yolov5/runs/train/your_yolo_model/weights/best.pt